# Fetch the value of the labels and the selected options in Group Drop Down in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am new to php, I have a group drop down in a HTML form and after submitting the form, I need to get the name of the group as well as the selected option in PHP.

```
<select name="assign_id">
    <optgroup label="Admins">
            <option value="1">John Smith</option>
            <option value="2">Jane Smith</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Editors">
            <option value="3">Brian Smith</option>
            <option value="4">Scott Smith</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Basic Users">
            <option value="3">Kevin Smith</option>
            <option value="4">Tanya Smith</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

For example in the above bunch of I codes I need to get the label "Admins" as well as the selected option "John Smith" after the form is submitted and save it in MySql Table using PHP.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: I know about forms, what I need is, both the label (or the group name)and the selected option's value after submitting the form. As I mentioned above it is about a group drop down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you to have progress in what you are doing!

```js
$("#assign_id").change(function(){
    var el = document.getElementById('assign_id');
    var text = el.options[el.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    
     var label = $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).closest('optgroup').prop('label');
     alert(text);
     alert(label);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="assign_id" id="assign_id">
    <optgroup label="Admins">
            <option value="1">John Smith</option>
            <option value="2">Jane Smith</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Editors">
            <option value="3">Brian Smith</option>
            <option value="4">Scott Smith</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Basic Users">
            <option value="3">Kevin Smith</option>
            <option value="4">Tanya Smith</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks but along with "John Smith", I need the value "Admins" as well.

Comment: Try running the snippet again. That might get what you wanted to. @GoodSpeed. I just put the values in alert just to see some results. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't u add an indicator of the group in the value of the options like:

```
<select name="assign_id">
<optgroup label="Admins">
        <option value="Admins_1">John Smith</option>
        <option value="Admins_2">Jane Smith</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Editors">
        <option value="Editors_3">Brian Smith</option>
        <option value="Editors_4">Scott Smith</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Basic Users">
        <option value="Basic_Users_3">Kevin Smith</option>
        <option value="Basic_Users_4">Tanya Smith</option>
</optgroup>
```

and in your php file use [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) like:

```
<?php $groupName = ( (substr($_POST['assign_id'],'Admins') != -1) ? 'Admins' : ( (substr($_POST['assign_id'],'Editors') != -1 ) ? 'Admins' : 'Basic_Users' ) ) ?>
```

and to get The real value of the option use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
<?php $optionValue = str_replace(array('Admins_','Editors_','Basic_Users_'),'',$_POST['assign_id']) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/*

Database: `testdb`

Table structure for table `groupnames`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `groupnames`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groupnames` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`groupname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Dumping data for table `groupnames`

INSERT INTO `groupnames` (`id`, `groupname`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Admins', '1'),
(2, 'Admins', '2'),
(3, 'Editors', '3'),
(4, 'Editors', '4'),
(5, 'Basic Users', '5'),
(6, 'Basic Users', '6');
COMMIT;

*/

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testdb"); //server,username,password,database
if(!$conn){
die("Database Connection Failed."); //if wrong server name,username,password or database name
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$grouplabel_name = $_POST['grouplabel_name'];
    echo $grouplabel_name; //displays the group label name and name from the group
}
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<select name="grouplabel_name">
<option></option>
    <?php
        $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM groupnames ORDER BY id ASC")or die(mysqli_error($conn));

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($query)){
                $grouplabel = $row->groupname; //group label
                $name = $row->name; //name from the group

                    if($grouplabel == "Admins"){
                    ?>
                    <optgroup label="Admins">
                        <option value="<?php echo $grouplabel.' - '.$name; ?>"><?php 
                            if($name == 1){
                            echo "John Smith"; 
                            }
                            elseif($name == 2){
                            echo "Jane Smith";
                            }
                    ?>    
                        </option>
                    </optgroup>

                    <?php
                    }
                    elseif($grouplabel == "Editors"){
                    ?>
                    <optgroup label="Editors">
                        <option value="<?php echo $grouplabel.' - '.$name; ?>"><?php 
                            if($name == 3){
                            echo "Brian Smith"; 
                            }
                            elseif($name == 4){
                            echo "Scott Smith";
                            }
                    ?>
                        </option>
                    </optgroup>

                    <?php
                    }
                    elseif($grouplabel == "Basic Users"){
                    ?>
                    <optgroup label="Basic Users">
                        <option value="<?php echo $grouplabel.' - '.$name; ?>"><?php 
                            if($name == 5){
                            echo "Kevin Smith"; 
                            }
                            elseif($name == 6){
                            echo "Tanya Smith";
                            }
                    ?>
                        </option>
                    </optgroup>
                    <?php
                    }
            }
        ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Hope it helps :)